# Default text not generating

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am learning C# and just started with VScode and it does not generate any of the defualt text my tutorial showed me such as this

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");    
    }
  }
}
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean generate... Is the console window opening? It should be, but it's possible it is closing almost immediately after execution, since it reach the end of the program.  Try putting a `Console.Read()` after the `WriteLine` as a way to "pause" the console before closing.

Comment: How did you create the project? Using the terminal: dotnet new console -n "MyConsoleApp" ?

Comment: Why don't you try Visual Studio Community?

Comment: [Read this post](https://www.michaelcrump.net/creating-and-debugging-console-apps-with-vscode/) and don't put questions against SO policy, which you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)